# Replacing simple switch with literal map. What map?

Tags: c++

I have the following pattern in a number of places:

```
unsigned key = getKey();
auto res = [=]() {
  switch (key)
  {
    case 12: return &x;
    case 14: return &y;
    case 81: return &z;
    default: fatal_error();
  }
}();
```

It's a map from non-consecutive integers, usually an enum, to some other set of values, usually function pointers. The switch construct works for this but contains a lot of line noise. The immediately invoked lambda can be replaced by assigning to a variable in exchange for a lot of `break;` statements.

What's the clean, canonical way to write this? For consecutive integers it could be:

```
std::array<ptr_t, 3> map = {{&x, &y, &z}};  
auto res = map[key];
```

One option is to use a map (ordered or unordered),

```
std::map<unsigned, ptr_t> map = {{12, &x}, {14, &y}, {81, &z}};
auto res = map[key];
```

Which is good in terms of code clarity but relatively unlikely to be stripped by the compiler as the map involves a tree and a bunch of heap allocations.

Another is via a hash function,

```
std::array<ptr_t, 4> map = {{&y, &z, nullptr, &x}};
auto res = map[hash(key)]; // don't want to write hash() each time
```

I don't mind if dispatch is via a near-perfect hash function into an array or via branches as long as the heap isn't involved. Can the above switch be improved upon?

suggestion from nwp:

```
using kvp_t = std::pair<unsigned, ptr_t>;
std::array<kvp_t, 3> m = {{
  {12, &x}, {14, &y}, {81, &z},
}};
auto res = std::find_if(m.begin(),m.end(),[=](kvp_t k) {
  return k.first == key;
})->second;
```

Comment: `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: unordered_map hits the heap. A hash table with an internal buffer would work though, especially if it had constexpr accessors

Comment: Is this just an example or are you actually using integer keys?  How many do you expect there to be?

Comment: Keep in mind that a switch is usually heavily optimized (with a jump table, ip-relative addressing etc.). Any map/hashmap/array accessing will most probably be slower. Maybe use a preprocessor?

Comment: How about an `std::array<std::pair<unsigned, ptr_t>>` together with `std::find_if`?

Comment: @Robinson The keys are all 32 bit unsigned integers. The values vary but are homogenous. Some cases have three or four keys, some as many as fifty.

Comment: I think your performance would be fine with nwp's suggestion.  Just a std vector or array and find_if.  I would value clarity for maintenance over everything else.

Comment: [Looks pretty similar](https://godbolt.org/g/y6VzEf) to me. Might want to see what your compiler does and if it ruins debug performance.

Comment: @nwp Looks good enough. Somewhat interesting that gcc sees through the array indirection and clang doesn't. Would you like to promote the comment to an answer?

Comment: I don't think an answer would add anything since you wrote the code already in the question. Also I am not at all convinced that it is actually an improvement. The original code looks less noisy to me and the goal was to reduce noise.

Comment: Prefer not to put references into a `map`. Use pointers instead (you'll need to make the variables static or global so that they don't disappear after execution leaves the scope).